# Angular - Dynamically load html that includes angular markups

Tags: html, angular

In Angular 9+ I can successfully convert a string to a html and then load that that html using innerHtml and bypassSecurityTrustHtml().

My question is it possible to also dynamically load/render the converted html to include and recognise angular/javascript markup language eg *ngIf, handle bars and click events.

Below is the code and stackblitz at the attempt so far but as you can see it doesn't recognise the markup.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-angular?file=app/app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  text: string = "Hello world";
  content: any;
  constructor(private domSantizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let body: any =
      '<div>{{text}}<div><br><button (click)="test()">Test</button>';
    this.content = this.domSantizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(body);
  }

  test() {
    alert("It works");
  }
}
```

Html

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a component for such an operation.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic we have a platform where are looking to implement custom style homepage to be stored as a string in db. If there is a way to attach the template to a component in runtime that would work but so far I think this is not possible

Comment: can you modifire static body string or they came somewhere ?

Comment: the string will be coming from an API retrieving from a database. Nb: The data itself will be secured as it is only set by admin hence no issue with XSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have researched and tried many solutions.
My research and trial results are below.

html

```
<div #container></div>
```

typescript side as below

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("container", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {}
  text: string = "asdasd";
  ngOnInit() {
    this.addComponent(
      `<div>{{text}}<div><br><button (click)="test()">Test</button>
       `,
      {
        text: "Hello word",
        test: function() {
          alert("It's work");
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private addComponent(template: string, properties?: any = {}) {
    @Component({ template })
    class TemplateComponent {}

    @NgModule({ declarations: [TemplateComponent] })
    class TemplateModule {}

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find(
      comp => comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    Object.assign(component.instance, properties);
    // If properties are changed at a later stage, the change detection
    // may need to be triggered manually:
    // component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-angular-kovivd?file=app/app.component.ts)

some posts I have reviewed

[compile dynamic Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular?answertab=active#tab-top)

[angular-html-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

[I think it makes the most sense :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093)

Comment: Wow I really didn't think this was possible. It works well thank you so much for taking the time and doing this, absolute legend!